# Rails 5.1 i18n changes from 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I am upgrading my Rails 4.2 app to 5.1. One of the tests I have, is to verify that all the English i18n strings have a counterpart in my other languages.

I noticed that this test fails now, since it seems like Rails 5.1 changed / moved some of the locale keys in the `errors` section. Here are some of my missing keys for example:

```
- errors.messages.required: 'must exist'
- errors.or: 'or'
- errors.array?: 'must be an array'
- errors.excludes?: 'must not include %{value}'
- errors.excluded_from?.arg.default: 'must not be one of: %{list}'
- errors.excluded_from?.arg.range: 'must not be one of: %{list_left} - %{list_right}'
```

So my question is: Does the question mark in the key name (like `errors.excludes?`) have a special meaning? Or should I just implement it verbatim in my other languages. For a key like `errors.excluded_from?.arg.range` - should my YAML just be like this?:

```
errors:
  excluded_from?:
    arg:
      range: ...
      default: ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this all just part of the standard `rails-i18n` setup?? I haven't seen those before; either I missed something, or this is some custom third party implementation?

Comment: Ahhhh wait, I found it. [Here](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-validation/blob/master/config/errors.yml) -- This is some custom stuff from the `dry-validation` ruby gem. It's not core rails. Yes, it seems you should structure your file as described.

Comment: @TomLord - super nice find. I see that this gem is indeed in my stack, since I am using the `config` gem. I guess I could probably ignore these keys then, I will investigate further. Thanks!